# Spring MongoTemplate: Possible to Get and Count all distinct values from Key value Object in each document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a large-ish dataset (+100,000) documents. In each document, there is a key value object called ProjectCategories for which I would like to be able to get distinct count on each of the values across the entire collection.

For example my document looks like this:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e5ae42fcc92f14c3a41208"),
    "userId" : "xxxx",
    "projectCreator" : {
        "userId" : "xxx|xxxx"
    },
    "hashTags" : [
        "Spring",
        "Java"
    ],
    "projectCategories" : {
        "60d76ef0597444095b8ab4b2" : "Backend",
        "60d76ef0597444095b8ab232" : "Infrastructure" 
    },
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2021-07-07T13:38:10.655Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-07-08T11:48:36.200Z"),

    "_class" : "xxxx.model.project.Project"
}
```

I would like to get back all the unique values and their counts. Something like this:

- Backend : 1002
- FrontEnd : 1232
- Infrastructure: 902

Is this possible to do using Java and mongoTemplate

Thanks for reading

Comment: You can do that calculation with an Aggregation query. First, use `$objectToArray` and convert the `projectCategories` object field to an array. Then, you can unwind and group/counts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @prasad_  By any chance do you know of any mongoTemplate examples online showing roughly how to do this? I can't seem to find anything.